# Restrict compilation to certain machines

Tags: trust, docker, git

I am a software developer in a big company. I just realised that I could technically clone the repository of my employers git repository. The infrastructure is in docker images.

So technically this is all I need to recreate the web server on my local laptop or another Server. Of course, I wouldn't do this. I don't think my employer should have so much trust in me or us employees. So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to restrict the code compilation to certain company computers?
2. How do other companies handle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For 1) the answer is sort of no. There are tools used to restrict code to a particular machine in various fields, by physical tokens, licence keys etc, but none are foolproof (DRM, or Digital Rights Management doesn't work) so the important bits are all in your question 2)

Various mechanisms should be in place:

- Theft is typically a criminal offence, so employees know that if they steal code they could end up in prison. This works rather well as a deterrent, however as it is not preventative, most companies will also have
- Data Loss Prevention tools, that will monitor for and alert on unapproved exfiltration of data
- Access controls on the repo such that only those people who require access will have it, and then only the minimum required for their role
- Searches for their code across Websites, online repos, or criminal trading sites

And various other tools depending on requirements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70487/discussion-between-rory-alsop-and-forest).